# Get custom attributes from material ui text field inside onChangeHandler

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am using react and material ui.

The markup for textfield is something like this

```
<TextField                    
    floatingLabelText="Email"
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
    ref="email"
    customAttr="customValue"
    errorText = {this.props.errors.email}
/>
```

My onChange handler is below

```
function onChange(e) {
   var customVal = e.target.getAttribute("customAttr");
   alert(customVal);  //undefined
}
```

I want to get the value of the my custom attribute when using material ui.

Please help!!

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this.

in `TextField`:

```js
    onChange={() => { this.props.onChange("customValue") }}
```

or without es6

```js
    onChange={function () { this.props.onChange("customValue") }}
```

and update `onChange` func:

```js
    function onChange (customVal) {
       alert(customVal)
    }
```